# Subtracting Columns Except When There is NA

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new variable that subtracts two columns only when both columns do not have NA, but has NA whenever one of the columns has NA. When I try to just subtract the columns, I only get a columns of NA. For instance, I am writing the command:

```
d$x3 <- d$x2 - d$x1
```

When I use the command above, I get:

```
x1   x2   x3
1    3    NA
1    NA   NA
NA   3    NA
NA   NA   NA
```

Based on looking at some other posts online, I tried to doing a workaround where I changed x1 to negative numbers and then used rowSums command, but then I got this:

```
x3 <- rowSums(df[,c("x1","x2")], na.rm = TRUE)

x1   x2   x3
-1   3    2
-1   NA   -1
NA   3    3
NA   NA   0
```

What I am trying to produce is:

```
x1   x2   x3
1    3    2
1    NA   NA
NA   3    NA
NA   NA   NA
```

Thanks for any help!

```
 df <- read.table( text="x1   x2
 1    3 
 1    NA 
 NA   3  
 NA   NA", header=T)
```

Comment: I do not understand how you can obtain the second line (`-1`) on your example `data.frame` then.

Comment: I do not want -1 on the second line. I want NA. But when I use a strategy that includes na.rm, all the NAs seem to become zero, in which case it 0-1=-1. I hope that clarifies! Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what's going wrong for you, as that is the result you should be getting, I think.  However, if you want to select rows that have no NAs, you could look at `complete.cases`.

Comment: I agree with @David_B: the first `data.frame` you shared is meaningful and I see no reason why you should obtain the second one. Any arithmetic operation including at least one `NA` result in NA, (except if explicitely omitted) since, by essence, we don't know the value of NA.

Comment: What you are describing as your objective is actually the default R behavior.  Unless there is something weird going on, it should work just like you want.  And I can't offhand think of anything that would cause it to implicitly replace the NAs with zeros before the subtraction like you show in your output, even if you have changed the global `na.action` option or something like that.  Try it with a fresh R session and see if it still happens.

Comment: Hi all, I edited my question to hopefully clarify the steps I've taken and what I'm trying to produce. For some reason, I'm not getting what I also thought would be the default behavior. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @tlev you can simply do this df$x3 <- (df$x1 - df$x2)

Comment: @tlev I added code from my deleted answer to read in the data.frame, as named df. If you read that in (copy and paste into R console), then use `df$x2 - df$x1`, do you not get your desired result?

Comment: I'm still getting all NAs  when I used the suggested code on the dataset I'm working with. My two variables are both dummy variables, so they are made up of 0s, 1s, and NAs. When I pull up the unique values for these two variables, it verifies that they indeed have 0s, 1s and NAs. But when I try to subtract one variable from the other using the same code many of you have suggested, it just gives me a column of NAs. Any thoughts on why this might be happening?